# Advise on object-oriented design

Tags: oop

I would like some help with a OOD query.

Say I have the following `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

It's a simple placeholder for customer related data. Next comes the `CustomerFactory`, which is used to fetch customers:

```
public static class CustomerFactory
{
    public static Customer GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        return null; // Pretend this goes off to get a customer.
    }
}
```

Now, if I wanted to write a routine named `UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)` can someone suggest where I could place this method?

Obviously I don't want to use the `Customer` class since that would be against SRP (Single Responsibility Principle), also I don't see it as a good idea to attach the method to the `CustomerFactory` class, since it's only role is to get customers from the database.

So it looks like I'm going to need another class, but I don't know what to name it.

Cheers.
Jas.

Comment: For future reference - there wasnt any need to mark this question as community wiki :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have called a Factory isn't a Factory at all. It's a Repository.

A [Factory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx) handles the instansiation of various classes sharing a common Interface or Class Hierarchy based on some set of parameters.

A [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) handles the retrieval and management of data.

The Repository would definitely have the `UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)` method in it as well as the `GetCustomer(int id)` method.

Comment: Ahh, great. This is where I've made things muddy for myself, by naming the class CustomerFactory, rather then CustomerRepository. That already seems better.

Answer (score 4):

You are more on less on your way to creating a **Repository**. Do something like this:

```
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    Customer SelectCustomer(int id);

    void UpdateCustomer(Customer customer);

    void DeleteCustomer(int id);

    void CreateCustomer(Customer customer);
}
```

Then create concrete implementations of this interface (the interface is really just because it's good practice to program against interfaces - you could skip it, though, although I would recommend that you keep it).

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't your UpdateCustomer routine be placed in your DAL (Data Access Layer).  You should define a class to handle inserts or updates to the database and then pass a customer object to it.

You could write the DAL class to handle all of this but I don't see any issue in storing it in your CustomerFactory class, although as mentioned it is not really a factory.